# Keras returns wrong value for sum

Tags: python, keras

I have this code to understand how Jaccard Index works and I am trying to implement it as a Keras custom metric, but the return of this function is wrong and I have no idea why (I am new to Keras btw).

This function creates a rectangular area to test intersections:

```py
def block(start, width=20, heigth=10, length=60):
    block = np.zeros((1, heigth, length))
    block[:, :, start:(start + width)] = 1
    return block.astype('uint8')
```

If I get a `block(10)` and a `block(20)` there should be two 10x20 blocks with a 10x10 area of intersection so the union must be `2*(10*20) - 10*10` which is confirmed by this Numpy line:

```py
np.sum(((block(10) + block(20)) > 0).astype('uint8'))
```

But when I try to use this Keras function:

```
def test(a, b):
    return K.sum(K.cast((a + b) > 0, dtype='uint8'))
```

The result is 44 when I call it with `K.eval(test(block(10), block(20)))`

EDIT (new test):

```
def test(a, b):
    return K.sum(a), K.sum(b), K.sum(a) + K.sum(b)

[K.eval(elem) for elem in test(block(10), block(20))]
```

This is the result: `[200, 200, 144]`

What am I doing wrong to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dtype of the Keras sum is inferred from the object that is summed over, so in this case the sum will be of type `uint8`. Your result is 300. `uint8` can take 256 different values, and `300 - 44 = 256`. If you take a closer look on your python code:

```
blocks = block(10) + block(20) # dtype='uint8'
mask = (blocks > 0) # dtype=bool
mask_as_uint = mask.astype('uint8') # dtype='uint8', which is an unnescessary conversion
np.sum(mask_as_uint) # dtype='uint64
```

So your result is of type `uint64`, while you ask Keras to give you a result in `uint8`. In fact the following gives 44 as an answer as well:

```
np.int8(300)
```

In short, switch to a bigger dtype for the sum or do the operations in an order manually where `uint8` doesn't have shortcomings.

Comment: Changing the line to `test(block(10).astype('float32'), block(20).astype('float32'))` should be enough? It did not work.

Comment: Try and change the sum to `K.sum(K.cast((a + b) > 0), dtype='uint32')`